Oracle SQL Developer - Find Database Object -- schema checkboxes shift position on restart - anyone have a fix for this?
I'm using Oracle SQL Developer Version 21.4.1.349 on Windows
We have a large number of schemas. I only work with 3 of them.
When I need to find something using the Find Database Object function, I only want to search those 3 schemas. I check just those boxes.
Here's where it gets weird. Every time I quit and reopen SQL developer (which I occasionally need to do because it freezes randomly, or I need to restart my laptop), it still has 3 boxes checked... but they're the wrong ones. The checks shift upwards by 1 position.
For example, if I had schemas named alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta theta and so on... and I cared about and checked gamma, epsilon, and eta. Upon a restart, the checked boxes will now be beta, delta, and zeta.
It's not just a visual bug, searching will search the contents of the newly checked schemas instead of the ones I originally selected.
Has anyone run into this? Is there a fix? It's really annoying. Not as annoying as the random freezing, but it seems there's no fix for that one.
Thank you!
